# Convert specific time in specific timezone to time in user’s timezone without using GNU date

Tags: osx, date

Specifically, what I want to know is: when it’s 10:00 (10AM) EST, what time is it in the user’s current time zone? At time of writing the answer to a user in the UK (GMT) would be 15:00 (3PM).

For my specific case I don’t even need the minutes or the day, just the hour (`15` in this example).

Most questions of this nature are concerned with converting the present time (now) or *from* the user’s timezone. At one point I even resorted to ruby for the transformation, but making it work from anything but UTC is a bit harder. I feel like there must be way to do it with `date`, but macOS uses BSD’s `date` and most answers use GNU’s.

Comment: You almost certainly do want the minutes, to handle the cases where the difference in times is not an integer number of hours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's pretty clunky, but this ought to do it on MacOS using only the shell and the `date` command:

Convert 2017-01-05 10:00:00 in North American eastern time to the system's local time zone:

```
date -r $(TZ=America/Montreal date -j 010510002017 +%s)
```

To convert that to a timezone other than the local one, prefix the outer command with the desired target timezone:

```
TZ=Australia/Sydney date -r $(TZ=America/Montreal date -j 010510002017 +%s)
```

Just beware the extremely bizarre date input format: `mmddHHMMYYYY`

Comment: Converting to seconds and then from seconds. That’s smart. Thank you, this is exactly what I needed. Added a recommended edit to cover my specific case.

Answer (score 1):

The POSIX APIs aren't very rich in this regard. You're probably better off using something like [pytz](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/) than system tools:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import datetime
import pytz

eastern = pytz.timezone('America/Montreal')
britain = pytz.timezone('Europe/London')
datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 5, 10, 0, tzinfo=eastern).astimezone(britain)
```

Comment: To be clear, I do *not* want the target timezone to be the UK. I want it to be the current one from the user. Also, if the answer has to not use `date`, I’d rather it use ruby, since I’m more familiar with it.

Comment: Fair enough about ruby. As for the target timezone, `Europe/London` is just an example. Use whatever target timezone you want instead, or `pytz.reference.LocalTimezone` for the local one from the environment.

Comment: Upvoted all the same since it was still a good answer. Thank you for the help!